# Headphones doesn't work on ubuntu start

Tags: 18.04, headphones

I'm using Ubuntu 18, headphones doesn't work when it's connected before system starts.
Only restarting system with headphones off solve the problem. Is there can be any common reason behind it?

Comment: well, my english is not the best

Comment: Indeed, I confirm this, and it is still the case in Ubuntu 19.04. I developped the habbit to plug in the headphone after the desktop has started. The command "alsactl restore" may restore your headphones without a need to reboot the system.